# How can I count matches between two columns based on specific text in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I have two columns; the first one represents the actual results, and the second one is the  predicted result. I want to count how many times the prediction matches the result based on specific text.

The data is like so:

```
Col A      Col B
Positive   Negative
Positive   Positive
Negative   Negative
Negative   Negative
Positive
Negative
```

So the number of matched cells with Positive value should be **1**, while the number of matched cells with Negative value should be **2**.

Keep in mind the match has to be in the **same row**.

I used the following formula, but unfortunately it gave me the number of all matched cells without being able to specify the text:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6=B1:B6)*1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then add another criteria:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6=B1:B6)*(A1:A6="Positive"))
```

And

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6=B1:B6)*(A1:A6="Negative"))
```

---

Or you can use COUNTIFS()

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Positive",B:B,"Positive")
```

And

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Negative",B:B,"Negative")
```

Comment: I'd go definitely with the `COUNTIFS`. But good to have a menu :)

Comment: @Scott Craner, thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

If the dataset only contains the 2 values 'Positive' and 'Negative' I will go for the Countifs (Answer from Scott Craner)
If you have more values then I would add a help column 
=A3=B3

[image]

And then count on the new column:
=Countif(C:C;TRUE)

[image]

Comment: Thanks @MBK for your well-explained answer.